# Ruby delete keys from hash only while printing without modifying the hash

Tags: ruby

I am a newbie to ruby. I am trying to delete keys which are passwords from the hash while printing the hash, with/without modifying the original hash

```
 request = {"name"=>"test-2", 
            "dns_zone_status"=>"valid", 
            "certificate_status"=>"valid", 
            "db_password"=>"GS*8qLiU", 
            "af_pass"=>"rk*pp2", 
            "master_password"=>"sfvrere", 
            "db_user"=>"testuser2"}
puts "request : #{request}"
puts "request : #{request.except("db_password","af_pass","master_password")}"
```

The first puts print the whole hash and the 2nd one errors `undefined method 'except' for #<Hash:0x00000001dbcd00> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: with or without?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Hash#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject), which is non-destructive and returns a hash.

```
puts "request : #{
  request.reject do |k,_|
    ["db_password","af_pass","master_password"].include?(k)
  end
}"
#request : {"name"=>"test-2", "dns_zone_status"=>"valid", "certificate_status"=>"valid", "db_user"=>"testuser2"}
```

As is commonly done, I've used an underscore for the block variable holding the value associated with the key `k` to tell the reader that it is not used in the block calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having to bring all of ActiveSupport in as a dependency (which is the gem implementing `Hash#except`, if you don't need it in other ways you can just inline this tiny method as:

```
puts "request : #{request.slice(*request.keys - ["db_password","af_pass","master_password"])}"
```

Comment: Got an error
undefined method `slice' for #<Hash:0x0000000103a0b0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Jill what version of Ruby are you using? (`Hash#slice` was new in v2.5.) It works fine with v2.6.5.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hash#except](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) method actually comes from [ActiveSupport](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), which is loaded by default in Rails but not in standalone Ruby.

However, that's easily remedied, all you have to is add the `activesupport` gem and one of the following requires:

```
# require everything in active support, the easy/lazy option
# this is what rails does and it's probably fine to do
# unless you really, really care about how much memory you use
require 'active_support/all'

# require only the hash extensions
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'

# require only this one specific method
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/except'
```

Note that the name of the gem (`activesupport`) and the library you require (`active_support`) are indeed named differently, which can be a little tricky to remember.

Comment: activesupport vs active_support: I still can't remember which one to use when! I get it wrong every time.